# using write() method, the file gets too big

Tags: java, android, arrays, fileoutputstream

I try to write to a file, the data that I receive from a socket , I store the data in an array but when I write them, the file gets too big ... 
I think it is caused by using a big array , as i don't know the length of the data stream...

But checking the method write it is stated that write(byte[] b) Writes b.length bytes from the specified byte array to this file output stream,
the write() method reads the length of the array but the length is 2000...
How can i know the length of the data that will be written?

```
...
byte[] Rbuffer = new byte[2000];
dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
dis.read(Rbuffer);
writeSDCard.writeToSDFile(Rbuffer);

...

void writeToSDFile(byte[] inputMsg){



    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/download");

    if (!(dir.exists())) {
         dir.mkdirs();
     }

    Log.d("WriteSDCard", "Start writing");

    File file = new File(dir, "myData.txt");

    try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        f.write(inputMsg);
        f.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(TAG, "******* File not found. Did you" +
                " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the   manifest?");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of reading the whole file at once, you can write it as you down load and then it doesn't matter how might it is. Read a bit from the InputStream and copy it to the OutputStream say 512 bytes to 8 KB at a time.

Comment: @peter-lawrey how can I read only few bits without losing the stream... as another stream will come (in the mean time...)

Comment: read the doc for the `read` method. it has a return value that is going to be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read()` returns the number of bytes that were read, or -1. You are ignoring both possibilities, *and* assuming that it filled the buffer. All you have to do is store the result in a variable, check for -1, and otherwise pass it to the `write()` method.

Actually you should pass the input stream to your method, and use a loop after creating the file:

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Your statement in a now-deleted comment that a new input stream is created per packet is not correct.

Comment: In order to pass it to the write method, I have to insert and an offset (i think it will be 0) as I want all the input stream to be inserted in the file... but after a number of messages i receive negative length, What does it mean, (is the transmition  finished?)

Comment: Yes. I did mention -1. Have you considered consulting the Javadoc?

Comment: Just realised, the file is not too big for the storage, the file is bigger than it should be. Given the expected size of the file might try a 2048 byte buffer. +1